# Windows version of Linux's 'which'?

Tags: powershell, command-line

In Linux's command line, to determine whether a given program is installed and in scope, I run `$ which [program name]` and see whether a path is output in response.

Now, for work, I use Windows and am starting to learn PowerShell.

How can I determine from the Windows command line, or PowerShell, whether a given program is installed?

Comment: you can use `get-command` in MS Powershell

Comment: Create a batch file `which.cmd` with the 2 lines `@set "file=%~$PATH:1"` and
`@if defined file echo %file%`.